# Existence of holomorphic solutions of a singular linear differential equation system

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

The problem is as follows: Given two functions $u$ and $v$ holomorphic in the punctured disk $D^{*}(0,a)$ in $\mathbb{C}$, $a>0$, does the differential system:
$$h_1^{\prime}=u(z)h_2(z); \quad h_2^{\prime}=v(z)h_1(z)$$ admit holomorphic solution in $D^{*}(0,a)$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's always the ever-popular $h_1 = h_2 = 0$.  But there might be no nonzero holomorphic solutions.

Consider the case $u(z) = 1/z$, $v(z) = 1/(4z)$. The general solution is 
$$h_1(z) =  c_1 z^{-1/2} + c_2 z^{1/2}, h_2(z) = \dfrac{c_1}{2} z^{-1/2} - \dfrac{c_2}{2} z^{1/2} $$

but unless $c_1 = c_2 = 0$, this can't be analytic in the punctured disk.

Comment: @ Robert: Thank you very much for your response. But I don't know how you define $z^{1/2}$ in the hole punctured disk.

Comment: That's the point: you can't.  In any non-punctured subdisk you do have  solutions given by my formula, for suitable branches of the square root, but you can't analytically continue the solution to the whole punctured disk.